# Use more than one font to drawstring

Tags: c#

I want to use drawString to print a sentance but some parts of it has to be bold. What is the best way to do this? Yes, I have considered using two drawString. But is there a intelligent way of using two drawStrings if we have to.

We cannot make any assumtion about the length of the sentance. However it is prepared in a format.

eg:

Say hello to **name**. Good afternoon 
**name**.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my old question on MSDN & it was answered. It works good. I hope it is the thing you want to find.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/8a050039-d74a-4ab5-9237-98615e10e303

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to call `DrawString` twice - you can write a small wrapper class (or extension method) that will do that for you.